# Is a closed simple curve of the plane entirely determined by the points of extremal or stationary curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry

The title is rather explicit: consider a $1$-periodic smooth map $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ injective on $[0,1)$ and let $C_f$ be the image of $[0,1]$ by $f$. Let $s$ be the abscissae on the curve and consider the points thereon where the derivative of the curvature with respect to $s$ vanishes. Do these points entirely determine $C_f$? Is the center of gravity of the considered curve given by the barycenter of these points with the value of the curvature at them as coefficients?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider 
$$
\alpha(t) = (4 \cos 2 \pi t,  \sin 2 \pi t)
$$
which is a nice ellipse. Now slightly adjust the parameterization, by letting
$$
s(t) = t + c * \sin(4 \pi t)
$$
where $c = 0.03$, and define
$$
\beta(t) = (4 \cos 2 \pi s(t),  \sin 2 \pi s(t))
$$
Clearly $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same image, but they differ as parameterized curves. Now let 
$$
\gamma(t) = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha(t) + \beta(t))
$$
The curvature extrema of $\gamma$ are once again at $t = 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4$, and for these values of $t$, we have $\alpha(t) = \beta(t) = \gamma(t)$. But elsewhere, $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ differ.

Have I actually done the derivative and curvature calculations? No. But I wrote a matlab program that pretty strongly convinced me. Here it is, if it'll be of any help to you.

```
function ell()
a = 4;
b = 1;
n = 200;
t = linspace(0, 1, 2000)
s = 0.03;
tp = t + s * sin(4 * pi * t)
dt = 1/n;
x = a * cos(2*pi*t);
y = b * sin(2*pi*t);

k = curvature(x, y, dt)
clf;
subplot(2, 2, 1);
plot(x, y, 'r');
subplot(2, 2, 3);
plot(k);

x1 = a* cos(2*pi*tp);
y1 = b * sin(2*pi*tp);
x2 = (x + x1)/2;
y2 = (y + y1)/2;
k2 = curvature(x2, y2, dt)
subplot(2, 2, 2);
plot(x2, y2, 'r');
subplot(2, 2, 4);
plot(k2);
figure(gcf)
end

function k = curvature(x, y, dt)
xp = x(2:end) - x(1:end-1);
yp = y(2:end) - y(1:end-1);
xpc = 0.5 * (x(3:end) - x(1:end-2));
ypc = 0.5 * (y(3:end) - y(1:end-2));
xpp = xp(2:end) - xp(1:end-1);
ypp = yp(2:end) - yp(1:end-1);
n = xpp .* ypc - ypp .* xpc;
d = (xpc.^2 + ypc .^2) .^ 1.5;
k = n ./ d;
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm afraid I don't really understand it, or maybe my phrasing was bad. You say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same image. Hence the purely geometrical object (namely, the ellipse) they define is the same. Maybe I should have said "the affine plane" instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And by the way, computer related stuff is rather useless to me. I may be old-fashioned, but all I use to (try to) do math are my brain, a pencil and sheets of paper.

Comment: They do have the same image, but since $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ are slightly displaced from one another for every $t$ (except multiples of $1/4$), we have that $\gamma(t) \ne \alpha(t)$, so the geometrical object defined by $\gamma$ is different. But it happens to match $\alpha$ at multiples of $1/4$, and its curvature extrema, like those of $\alpha$, occur at exactly those points. If this still doesn't make sense, I can try to do the actual curvature computations, but they're likely to be a mess.

Comment: Ok, the curvature extrema occur at the same points, but the actual values of the curvature at these points are different for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, aren't they?

Comment: I believe they might be. But since your question asked "do these points entirely determine $C_f$," I figured that was OK. If you'd asked "do these points and their associated curvatures entirely determine ...", I'd still bet the answer was "no" -- the perturbation would just have to be zero to second order at the critical points -- but that'd take a bit more work, and I didn't see a reason to answer a question that wasn't asked. :)

Comment: You have a point there. I should have paid more attention while trying to translate the picture I had in mind into words, mea culpa. What about the second question?

Comment: As I said, I very much suspect that the answer is still "no". Here's how I'd show it, if I had the time to work through the details: 1. again use 4-fold symmetry, so you only have to build a curve in the first quadrant that. 2. As a first curve, use an ellipse of radii 1 and 4. 3. Throw away most of the quarter-ellipse, giving you just a tiny arc near $(0, 1)$ and another near $(4,0)$. You know the direction and curvatureat the "join points". Think of building a monotone function $\theta(t)$ on [0, 1] whose initial and final values and derivatives match this; then "integrate".

Comment: When you integrate starting at the top arc, the other end might not match the right-hand arc...but you get to adjust the monotone function, and doing so will move the endpoint up or down (if you adjust near $t = 0$ or left-right (if you adjust near $t = 1$). All you have to do is keep it monotone, so you've got lots of freedom. That's why I believe it can be done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21162/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-john-hughes).